# How can the values of radio button and select options be passed to next page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two forms. When I click "submit" in the first one, it takes me to the second one. I'm trying to pass two information through my form. In details, suppose I've selected radio button 2 and option 3 in my first form. When I go to the second form, I want radio button 2 and option 3 already selected. How can this be done in html or php?

My codes are given below.

```
<form action="form2" method="post">    
   <p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_1">Radio 1</p>
   <p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_2">Radio 2</p>
   <p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_3">Radio 3</p>
   <select name="select">
      <option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option_3">Option 3</option>
   </select>    
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">    
</form>
<form>
   <p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_1">Radio 1</p>
   <p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_2">Radio 2</p>
   <p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_3">Radio 3</p>
   <select name="select">
      <option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option_3">Option 3</option>
   </select>    
</form>
```

Comment: You should google [multi step form with php](https://www.google.com/search?q=multi+step+form+with+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Form 2 you would want to do something like this:

```
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_1" <?php if($_POST['radio'] == "radio_1") echo "checked";?>>Radio 1</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_2" <?php if($_POST['radio'] == "radio_2") echo "checked";?>>Radio 2</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_3" <?php if($_POST['radio'] == "radio_3") echo "checked";?>>Radio 3</p>
```

Also check `if (isset($_POST['radio']))` somewhere to avoid errors.
Then do the same for yor `select`-fields.

Answer (score 0):

Inside form 2, you need to retrieve the `POST` data from first form and do the checking inside form's element directly :

```
Form 2:
<?php
$postData = $_POST;
<form>
  Radio:
    <p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_1" <?php if($postData['radio'] == "radio_1" ) echo 'checked'; ?>>Radio 1</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_2" <?php if($postData['radio'] == "radio_2" ) echo 'checked'; ?>>Radio 2</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio_3" <?php if($postData['radio'] == "radio_3" ) echo 'checked'; ?>>Radio 3</p>

  Select:
    <select name="select">
      <option value="option_1" <?php if($postData['select'] == "option_1" ) echo 'selected'; ?>>Option 1</option>
      <option value="option_2" <?php if($postData['select'] == "option_2" ) echo 'selected'; ?>>Option 2</option>
      <option value="option_3" <?php if($postData['select'] == "option_3" ) echo 'selected'; ?>>Option 3</option>
    </select>
 </form>
```